# GnuCash get quotes on stock price from the internet

Tags: gnucash

I have followed the instructions [here](http://www.askmeaboutlinux.com/?p=1709), using the exact example, to have automatic stock price updates in GnuCash. When I click `price editor -> Get Quotes` it returns in a warning `Unable to retrieve quotes for these items: NS:HDIL.NS` (also there is another one I tried too).

I installed `gnc-fq-update` following the instructions on the GnuCash mailing list [here](http://gnucash.1415818.n4.nabble.com/Installing-activeperl-for-automatic-retrieval-of-quotes-td4656798.html#a4656799). And when I type into the terminal `cpan -D Finance::Quote` as instructed to do so in the GnuCash wiki for CPAN the terminal returns

```
Going to read '/home/anthony/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 14 May 2014 02:06:11 GMT
Finance::Quote
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (no description)
    E/EC/ECOCODE/Finance-Quote-1.31.tar.gz
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Finance/Quote.pm
    Installed: 1.31
    CPAN:      1.31  up to date
    Erik Colson (ECOCODE)
    eco@ecocode.net
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the particular stock HDIL.NS I was trying to retrieve. Opening up a terminal and trying some of the commands listed in the GNUcash CPAN wiki [here](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/CPAN) showed that my installation is fine. For example in terminal to find amazon share price using yahoo works great

```
$ gnc-fq-dump yahoo AMZN
Finance::Quote fields Gnucash uses:
    symbol: AMZN                 <=== required
      date: 05/19/2014           <=== required
  currency: USD                  <=== required
      last: 296.755              <=\       
       nav:                      <=== one of these
     price: 296.755              <=/        
  timezone:                      <=== optional
```

Which is all OK. But the same for HDIL.NS and it can't find it (at least using yahoo)

```
$ gnc-fq-dump yahoo HDIL.NS
Finance::Quote fields Gnucash uses:
    symbol: HDIL.NS              <=== required
      date: ** missing **        <=== required
  currency: ** missing **        <=== required
      last: 0.00                 <=\       
       nav:                      <=== one of these
     price:                      <=/        
  timezone:                      <=== optional

** This stock quote cannot be used by gnucash!!
```

Using an alternative to yahoo may resolve the issue the command `gnc-fq-check` shows alternatives to yahoo (I haven't bothered to check and find one)

```
$ gnc-fq-check
("1.31" "cse" "india" "vwd" "yahoo_nz" "ukfunds" "australia" "amfiindia" "usfedbonds" "bitcoin_gbp" "canada" "yahoo" "bitcoin_aud" "adig" "bux" "bitcoin_eur" "aiahk" "mtgox_sek" "bsero" "mtgox_hkd" "bitcoin_pln" "yahoo_australia" "unionfunds" "lerevenu" "asia" "tsx" "sixfunds" "indiamutual" "bse" "bitcoin_nzd" "hungary" "mtgox_gbp" "known_currencies" "mtgox_chf" "tnetuk" "fidelity_direct" "goldmoney" "tdwaterhouse" "trustnet" "mtgox_thb" "ftportfolios_direct" "cominvest" "morningstar" "ftportfolios" "mtgox_usd" "ind" "tdefunds" "bitcoin_rub" "bitcoin_nok" "mstaruk" "hu" "za" "bitcoin_usd" "mtgox_eur" "fundlibrary" "stockhousecanada_fund" "mtgox_pln" "yahoo_europe" "mtgox_sgd" "platinum" "mtgox_nok" "bitcoin_hkd" "maninv" "tsp" "financecanada" "usa" "troweprice" "france" "nasdaq" "bmonesbittburns" "bitcoin_thb" "mtgox_cny" "yahoo_asia" "mtgox_cad" "troweprice_direct" "tiaacref" "seb_funds" "bitcoin_jpy" "bitcoin_cny" "mtgox_aud" "ftfunds" "yahoo_brasil" "greece" "fidelity" "mtgox_nzd" "fetch_live_currencies" "romania" "dwsfunds" "finland" "hex" "brasil" "asegr" "deka" "nyse" "canadamutual" "asx" "mtgox_jpy" "mtgox_rub" "yahoo_json" "finanzpartner" "za_unittrusts" "fool" "citywire" "bitcoin_sek" "bitcoin_sgd" "uk_unit_trusts" "dutch" "sixshares" "nzx" "bitcoin_cad" "bitcoin_dkk" "aex" "nz" "bitcoin_chf" "vanguard" "europe" "bourso" "morningstarjp" "mtgox_dkk")
```

Comment: I should credit that I received help from the GNUcash mailing list [here](http://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2014-May/054720.html).

Comment: Note that there is no reason to run the above command with sudo.